# Prove $\ \frac{x}{2x-\arctan x } $ continuous

Tags: calculus

$$\ f(x) = \frac{x}{2x-\arctan x } $$

Prove that $\ f(x) $ isn't continuous at only one single point.

Obviously $\  x = 0  \Rightarrow 2x-\arctan x = 0 $ and therefore it isn't continuous at $\ x = 0 $ but how can I show that the are no other points?

I was thinking about the graph of $\ g(x) =  \arctan x $ which gravitate between $\ -\pi/2 $ to $\ \pi/2 $ and so the only option for the $\ 2x - \arctan x  = 0 $ only if $\ x = 0 $.

but that's not enough as a proof. I guess I should assume there is another point and get contradiction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We want to show that $2x-\arctan x =0$ has only one root, $x=0$.

Let $g(x)=2x-\arctan x$. Then $g'(x)= 2 - \frac{1}{1+x^2} \geq 1$.

Assume for a contradiction that $g$ has another root: $r$.

As $g$ is continuous and differentiable everywhere, and $g(0)=g(r)$, we can apply Rolle's theorem.

By Rolle's theorem, $g'$ has a root between $0$ and $r$.

But we found that $g' \geq 1$. Contradiction. There are no other roots.